# Understanding TreeSet behaviour

Tags: java, equals, hashcode, treeset

I have a KeyValuePair class which is sorted by value & then key and being compared (with overridden equals and hashCode on key's int value). When I try to add 2 KeyValuePair with the same key, I expect it to replace the previous value, but it doesn't.

```
public class KeyValuePair  implements Comparable<KeyValuePair> {
    private Integer key;
    private Integer value;
    
    public KeyValuePair(Integer key, Integer value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(KeyValuePair kv){  //for sorting
        int diff = value - kv.value;
        if(diff == 0) {
            diff = key - kv.key;
        }
        return diff;
        //return diff>0?1:(diff<0?-1:0);   // this is also not solving the problem
    }  

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {       //for comparing duplicate based on key
        if (!(obj instanceof KeyValuePair)) {
            return false;
        }
        return ((KeyValuePair) obj).key.intValue() == this.key.intValue();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {     //for comparing duplicate based on key
        return key.intValue();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "{key: " + key + ", value:" + value + "}";
    }
}
```

Driver class

```
import java.util.*;

public class TreeSetEx {

    private TreeSet<KeyValuePair> allData = new TreeSet<>();

    private void add(Integer key, Integer value){ //O(log(n))
        allData.add(new KeyValuePair(key, value));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSetEx kvStroe = new TreeSetEx();
        kvStroe.add(9,10);
        kvStroe.add(1,8);
        kvStroe.add(1,2);

        System.out.println(kvStroe.allData);
    }
}
```

Output expected: [{key: 1, value:8}, {key: 9, value:10}]

Actual output getting: [{key: 1, value:2}, {key: 1, value:8}, {key: 9, value:10}]

Why isn't TreeSet replacing the new KVPair if the equals/hashCode has been overridden to compare with only key?

Comment: `TreeSet` doesn't use `equals()` and `hashCode()` - it solely relies on the `compareTo()` method. See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html): _a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method_

Comment: How to handle it if I want to sort by value and keep it unique by key?

Comment: Should key 1 rank at 2 or 8?

Comment: 2, as I would want it to be replaced based on key (1)